# Angularjs: ReferenceError: reference to undefined property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am confused by my Angularjs' controller(I guess my controller is also confused by my code anyway...).
So I have groups and users, the user can select the group he has. but it seems i can not access to the SelectedClass in user. Console told me it is undefined, but i already defined it as
    `$scope.SelectedClass = {};` at the top of the controller.
Here is my group:

```
    $scope.SelectedClass = {};
    $http.get('/groups').then(function(result){
         console.log(result);
         $scope.groups = result.data;
         $scope.SelectedClass = $scope.groups[0];
         $scope.changed = function() {
    console.log($scope.SelectedClass);
    } });

   $http.get('/users').then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
    $scope.allusers = {};
    $scope.allusers = result.data;
    var k = 0;

    console.log($scope.SelectedClass.group_id);
});
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you post the same structure of `result.data`?

Comment: "Console told me it is undefined". Is `undefined` the result of `console.log($scope.SelectedClass.group_id);`, i.e. the line you have in the success handler of the call to `/users`, or is it the result of  `console.log($scope.SelectedClass);` ?

Comment: @Arulkumar thank you for the reply. I can use console.log to get the result.data.

Comment: @MichaelP. the console shows the line of console.log($scope.SelectedClass.group_id); is undefined. i can use console.log to print out console.log($scope.allusers);

Answer (score 0):

Alright, just figured it out it is a super stuuuuupid error.

The data is null in my dummy database.`$scope.groups[0]` is null. That is why it is said undefined.

I guess next time I need to double check my database.